# Access post value in js

Tags: javascript

Here is my sample code in js which display a form with textbox **name=q** and a submit button.

```
var imghtml='<div id="qrfile"><canvas id="out-canvas" width="320" height="240"></canvas>'+
    '<form name="test" action="qr.js" method="get"><div id="imghelp">Enter student id'+
    '<br> manually<br>'+
    '<input type="text" name="q"/><input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()">'+
    '</div></form>'+
'</div>';
```

I want to capture the value when user click on submit button, the value is display in a div. i've create the function **myFunction()** below:

```
function myFunction(){
 document.getElementById("result_1").value=`q`;
}
```

the error is that i've wrongly capture `q` which is textbox name. any help

Comment: you are saying you wanted to capture the value but indeed you are assigning the value into `result_1` by `document.getElementById("result_1").value='q';`, why?

Comment: result_1 is in my html page where the result will be displayed... i need the textbox value to be assign to document.getElementById("result_1").innerHTML= ???

Comment: So you got the syntax to access the `value` of a form element for _writing_ into it already – but you’re not able to use the _same_ syntax to _read_ the value of another field in the same way …?

Answer (score 0):

Give your textbox an id and find that id using `document.getElementById`. Then you'll be able to get the value in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Give the field an ID then access/set the value in the way Suman suggested or using jquery instead you could do the following

```
    $("#result_1").val() //Retrieve
    $("#result_1").val("q") //Set
```